# Android Facebook Login Default Activity Class Name Splash Screen

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, splash-screen

I have decided to integrate Facebook Login into my project! On the google document, it asked me to give the `Default Activity Class Name`.

I want to do the login in my `Login Activity`, but I have a `Splash Activity` (just a splash screen using Lottie) before the `Login Activity` which in Manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".views.activities.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

So should I use it as the `Default Activity Class Name`?  Or is there any way around this?
Thank you!